# Positive & negative shocks in a VAR model and impulse response function in R

Tags: r, time-series, vector-autoregression

I have two general questions about impulse response functions in R using the package **vars**. Take a look at this code:

```
library(vars)
data(Canada)

var.2c <- VAR(Canada, p = 2, type = "const")
plot(irf(var.2c, impulse = "e", response = c("prod", "rw", "U"), boot = T))
```

It produces the impulse responses to a shock in the variable "e". My Questions:

1. Is this a positive or a negative shock in e?
2. Assuming this a a positive shock, how can I change it into a negative shock?

   I think, the shocks in a VAR-model are symmetric so in order to obtain the negative shock I should change the sign of the impulse response function? Am I right so far?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Kind of old, I know, but I had the same question and came up with something. So I hope it helps in the future. Another way to check whether you have a positive or negative shock is by focusing on the IRF of e with e. Just check the first value, and if it is positive, then you can know that you are considering a positive (an increase) e shock

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can say it is a positive shock, the impulse response is: How would e.g. "prod" react to a structural shock in "e", that is a structural shock of size 1, to understand it further than that you need to know the nature of the structural shocks;

from the VAR(p) you describe you get a covariance matrix. Lets call this covariance matrix  $\Sigma$, this  $\Sigma$ can be decomposed (Cholesky decomposition) like

$\Sigma=PP'$ where $P$ is an invertible lower triangular matrix. And the structural shocks, $u$, ($u = u_e, u_U, u_{\mathrm{prod}}, u_{\mathrm{rw}}$) are given by $u= \varepsilon\cdot P^{-1}$, $\varepsilon$ being the residuals from the VAR.

The impulse response is e.g. the change in "prod" when "e" changes with $u_e$.

Where is a positive or negative shock doesn't matter, a negative shock would just have the mirrored effect. Hope it helps!

Comment: "Where is a positive or negative shock doesn't matter"
-> oh, it does ;). I am considering an empirical analysis of monetary shocks. Therefore I need to construct a positiv interest rate shock and a negativ shock in the money aggregate M3.

Comment: What I mean is that there is a positive 1 in front of the correspondant, replace it with a negative 1, and you'll have your negative shock. :-)

Comment: All statistical functions work in that way. A positive shock increases say variable  X by 1 % , negative shock is supposed to decrease  variable X by 1 %. Is this correct?